# Pass Memory Stream Image Directly into Tesseract OCR (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, winapi, tesseract

I am currently feeding an image into Tesseract through a file path on my machine, but I want to expand on this and feed an image that has been provided through a memory stream and pass that as my image for Tesseract to perform OCR. I would ideally prefer a PowerShell solution.

*To add to this, I do not want to install system dependencies. I would like to place any necessary components all within one directory.

**What I am currently doing:**

```
./tesseract.exe "$Desktop_Path\OCRImage.png" stdout -l eng --psm 6
```

**What I would like to achieve:**

```
./tesseract.exe $OCRImage stdout -l eng --psm 6
```

I already have a way to capture the streamed image into PowerShell, but not sure how to take it beyond this and apply to the Tesseract parameter call above.

```
$OCRImage = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromStream($MemStream_Image)
```

I have found the following links below, but unaware how to fully implement in PowerShell.

[How do I pass File Stream to Tesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55108917/how-do-i-pass-file-stream-to-tesseract)

[How to provide image to Tesseract from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110300/how-to-provide-image-to-tesseract-from-memory)

https://github.com/jourdant/powershell-paperless/blob/master/tesseractlib.psm1

Comment: Why don't you use tesseract as a .dll? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Tesseract or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70956747/build-tesseract-as-dll-dynamic-link-library

Comment: @SimonMourier I have tried the approach of using the Tesseract50.dll Add-Type in PowerShell and unfortunately could not get it working. Using ```Add-Type -Path ".\Tesseract50.dll"``` generates an error that says ```Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to 
contain an assembly manifest.```

Comment: Okay, I dug a little deeper and took the Nuget package and extracted the Net48 "Tesseract.dll" and that seems to work/import. Now, I am running into an issue when trying to call the ```$pix = [Tesseract.PixConverter]::ToPix($OCRImage)```. It generates ```Exception calling "ToPix" with "1" argument(s): "Failed to find library "leptonica-1.82.0.dll" for platform x64."``` I believe I just don't have all the necessary dependencies even though I added the leptonica.dll in the same folder. Potentially point me in the right direction?

Comment: use procmon from sysinternals https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon filter by powershell process name and you'll see what's missing. It's seems the leptonica-1.82.0.dll needs vcruntime140.dll (install VS redidstributable see https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract/).

Comment: @SimonMourier So, I already had vcruntime140.dll at the machine level. I ended up placing that .dll and then adding the necessasry x64 folder structure that contained the .net Tesseract wrapper from charlesw and now all works. For my situation, it was finding the necessary components and wanting to read from the same directory and not through the system itself. Thanks for the help.